# xquery/xpath- how to get number of descendant nodes of a particular type

Tags: xpath, xquery

Take a look at the sample XML below--

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="1">
        Some random text
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        Some random text
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        Some random text
    </div>
    <p> Some more random text</p>
    <div id="4">
        Some random text
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, how do I find out the number of divs within the main div using Xquery? And how to do this in XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following XPath:

```
count(div[@id="main"]/div)
```

The function `count` does the counting, the main `div` is selected by its `id`.

Comment: This only produces correct result if all of the following conditions are true: 1. The initial context node is a parent of a `div` with `id='main'`; 2. There are no nested `div` elements that are descendants of the "main" div; 3. There is a single `div` in the document that has `id='main'`. While condition 3 is usually satisfied in an XHTML document (though this cannot be guaranteed), conditions 1. and 2. can be generally false.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I am trying to help, not to do someone else's work :-)

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expressions below can be used both in XPath and XQuery. This is so, because XPath (2.0) is a proper subset of XQuery.

**Use**:

```
count(/*//div)
```

If "the main div" isn't the top element of the XML document, and this is the only `div` whose `id` attribute has string value of `"main"`, use:

```
count((//div[@id='main'])[1]//div)
```

If it is guaranteed that the `div` children of the "main div" dont have `div` descendents, use:

```
count((//div[@id='main'])[1]/div)
```

**Do note**: The XPath pseudo-operator `//` can be very inefficient -- this is why, always try to avoid using it, whenever the structure of the XML document is statically known and specific paths can be used.

Comment: Should be the answer as OP specified "descendants" rather than direct childnodes.

Comment: @smerny, There aren't any "direct childnodes" specified in any of the expressions in this answer. Where do you see such?

Comment: I said that your answer should be the selected one (I used it myself for my similar issue). I explained that the reason that I believe this is because the original post asked specifically for "descendant nodes" rather than only direct childnodes (as the selected answer would get). I posted this in case other people like me come to this expecting the answer to do what the question asked.